# Trying to make the mouse move the camera up and down. but the left and right is walking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]float mouseSensitivity;

    private Transform parent;
    Vector2 turn;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        parent = transform.parent;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Rotate();
    }

    void Rotate(){
        float mousex = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        parent.Rotate(Vector3.up, mousex);

        float mousey = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime; ///.deltaTime;
        parent.Rotate(Vector3., mousey);

        // turn.x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        // turn.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        // transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-turn.y, turn.x, 0);
        
    }
}
```

This is the code for the camera I have written and been on it for like a day but don't know that much about coding so all I see just confuses me. Basically trying to make the camera move up and down with the mouse but it isn't working but the left and right are walking

Comment: You are missing `parent.Rotate(Vector3.***, mousey);` not sure what property you are looking to have there `Vector3.down`?

Comment: oh forgot the down was trying Vector.right or left before but it was just rotating the player body. Thanks will try the .down now

Comment: tried the vector3.down but no change the camera isnt going up or down still just side to side. I know i can use cinemamachine but i dot get what i need

Answer (score 0):

Try Replace

```
float mousey = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime; 
///.deltaTime;
    parent.Rotate(Vector3., mousey);
```

with

```
float mousey = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime; 
///.deltaTime;
    parent.Rotate(Vector3.right, mousey);
```

or

```
float mousey = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime; 
///.deltaTime;
    parent.Rotate(Vector3.forward, mousey);
```